# Real-time audio classification using Python

Tags: python, audio, deep-learning, real-time

I want to make a real-time audio classification using python. I have a trained deep learning model but I only only give it wav file as an input. I want to make it real-time where it will use microphone as an input. Is that possible? If so, how will I do it?

Comment: It’s certainly possible, but what level of detail do you need in an answer? What would an acceptable answer look like to you?

Comment: like, give me suggestions on how to do it. As I've said I only give my model wav file to predict. I want to make it real-time wherein it will use the data from the mic and predict it. I just don't know where to start in that matter.

Comment: For an SO answer that would be reasonable for others to find useful I think the word count would be pretty high. There could maybe some middle ground, but it's quite tricky to gauge what can and cannot be assumed to be prior knowledge, which I hope you can appreciate. If the question is _Where to start..._ then a good place will always be open source repositories of similar projects. https://github.com/search?q=Machine+learning+audio but I think that's true for any _where do I start..._ question

Comment: If you trained your model on wavs, then it is trained on PCM data. If you've normalised that data to a consistent range (e.g `+1.0` to `-1.0`) then that should actually be pretty sufficient. you should just need to send successive frames of audio to be classified, but then your classification needs to run fast enough. At that point we need to chat optimisations and what concessions can be made. Is python fast enough or could cython be useful? Hopefully you see how quickly this spirals.